# Open file from VSCode file explorer using keyboard?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have switched focus to the explorer using `cmd+shift+E`. I have selected a file in the explorer using the arrow keys.

I have found that `ctrl+enter` opens the file in a new tab.

How do I preview the file?

How do I open the file?

Comment: What does macOS have to do with Explorer?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I mean the VSCode file explorer. I have clarified my title a bit.

Answer (score 25):

On Mac, if the File Explorer is visible in your [VSCode Side Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) and the file you want to view is selected, just press the **space bar**.

To navigate between files:

- Give File Explorer focus (Cmd-Shift-E).
- Use the Up or Down arrow keys to navigate to your desired file.
- Press the **space bar**. Your desired file should appear in the Editor.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was so confused why I couldn't easily open files using my keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

### Built-in Command Overview

When working with VSCode on Windows, you can use the following commands to open/preview files from the explorer:

- Give the editor focus with `workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView`. Default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>
- Preview the highlighted file in the explorer with `list.select`. Default keybinding: <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Preview the highlighted file in the explorer in a new tab with `explorer.openToSide`. Default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Once the file preview is in focus and you want to open the file so it remains in the editor, use `workbench.action.keepEditor` . Default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

As of writing this, it seems it is not possible to keybind an action that directly opens the file from the explorer. Fortunately, we can remedy this with the macros extension as seen below.

**Note:** As for Mac, my understanding is that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the explorer will rename the file. Use the default shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>, or open the keyboard shortcuts menu and map `list.select` to something you want to use to open the file preview from the explorer. You could also remap `renameFile` from <kbd>Enter</kbd> to something else, and then use <kbd>Enter</kbd> for `list.select`.

---

### Adding a Keybinding to Open a File Directly (Non-preview)

If you want to add a keyboard shortcut to directly open a file from the explorer list, without it opening as a preview, you can use the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension.

1. Install the macros extension.
2. Open the `settings.json` file and add the following.  This will create a macro called `openFileAndKeep` that opens the file preview and then tells it to remain open.

   ```
    "macros": {
        "openFileAndKeep": [
            "list.select",
            "workbench.action.keepEditor"
        ]
    },
   ```
3. Open the `keybindings.json` file and add the following.

   ```
    {
        "key": "enter",
        "command": "macros.openFileAndKeep",
        "when": "listFocus"
    }
   ```

Now when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your explorer file list has focus, it will open the file in a non-preview state. Of course, you can also configure this to whatever key combination you desire.

Note: There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871) for adding macro functionality to vscode, so we might be able to achieve this without an extension in the future.

Comment: thanks for the macro

Comment: Cmd+Down was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To open a new VSCode instance at the folder of the currently opened file, you can do this:

Open Keyboard Shortcuts and search for the key command `workbench.action.files.openFileFolderInNewWindow`.

You will have to set a new keyboard shortcut to it, so pick one and assign it. I used <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and remapped that previous one since I didn't use it.

Then when you have a file open, you can just hit the keyboard shortcut, ie. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and it will open a new VSCode instance in that file's folder.